# Why do baby mammals tend to play?

Tags: evolution, behaviour

Why do babies of any mammal tend to play ? From humans to small dog pups, cubs of a lion, baby bears, etc.

*I am not sure if the tag I chose is correct or not. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Because it is a way to try things and learn.

Comment: Play has been described for [some birds](http://biosci-labs.unl.edu/avcog/research/articles/CmpAvianPlay.pdf). See also [here](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=jkiTQ8dIIHsC&oi=fnd&pg=PR10#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: If you find the book Sociobiology, by E.O. Wilson, it writes an entire section on the subject. It seems to be a preparation for adult life, simulating behaviors necessary for an adult (e.g. fight, hunt, etc). Though I don't know why it would have evolved more in mammals...

Comment: Related: [**Why does a housecat (or other predator) play with it's food before killing and eating it? Does it make the food taste better?**](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/19945/why-does-a-housecat-or-other-predator-play-with-its-food-before-killing-and-e)